# Remove the comma after the last number in a loop

Tags: java

this is my code

```
 System.out.println("Enter any integer number ");
int number = scan.nextInt();
while (number > 0) { System.out.print( number % 10 + ",");number = number / 10;}
```

To clarify if the user enter 1234
the output should be 4,3,2,1,

how can i edit the code to remove the comma after the last num?
something like 4,3,2,1

Comment: I wouldn't have written a line of code to show the OP, I would have just said to write the comma first on every iteration through the loop after the first. (give a man a fish, he eats for a day.....)

Answer (score 5):

Since everyone is having a field day, here's mine:

```
while (number > 0) {
    System.out.print( number % 10 + ((number/=10)>0 ? "," : ""));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most elegant approach I have picked along the way:

```
String delimiter = "";
while (number > 0) { 
   System.out.print(delimiter + number % 10);
   number /= 10;
   delimiter = ",";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following

```
if (number > 0) {
    System.out.print( number % 10 );
    number = number / 10;
    while (number > 0) { 
        System.out.print("," + (number % 10) );
        number = number / 10;
    }
}
```

Print the first element and then for all the other ones prepend a `,`. In this way, you always end with a

```
, X
```

The other options are doing unnecessary `if` checks.

Comment: Could the `while` loop be nested into the `if` after `number /= 10`?  After all, if `(number > 0)` evaluated false the first time, won't it evaluate false for the `while` loop as well, so we shouldn't need to check it twice if it failed the first time?

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
while (number > 0) {
    System.out.print(number % 10);
    number = number / 10;
    if (number > 0)
        System.out.print(",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick:

```
while (number > 0) {
        System.out.print(number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
        if(number!=0) System.out.print(",");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sotirios's solution works but here's an alternative:

```
// replacing "scan" with an example number.
int start = 123456789;
for (int number = start; number > 0; number = number / 10) {
    if(number < start)
        System.out.print(',');
    System.out.print(number % 10);
}
```

This will DRY up the calculation of the count down (number/10) but does the test to see if it's not the first one in each loop. I think that that test, however, would turn out to be faster than doing string arithmetic ("," + (number % 10)).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter integer : ");

    x = scan.nextInt();

    for(x = 4; x>1; x = x-1)
    {
        System.out.print(x + ",");
    }
    if (x != 0) // this is so the last number doesn't end with a comma
    {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
```

Comment: this definitely works if it loops round 4 down to 1.

Answer (score -2):

All the code that was showed here is invalid because the user can enter 0 and 0 should be printed out.

The valid code will look the following way

```
do
{
    System.out.print( number % 10 );
    number = number / 10;
    if ( number != 0 )
        System.out.print( "," );
} while ( number != 0 );
```

Comment: OP clearly states `while (number > 0)`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, I think he made the same mistake as others.

Comment: So OP doesn't know what they want?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis. The problem is not whether he knows or not. The problem is usually this mistake is common among beginners. They forget that zero is a valid number and can be entered by the user or that the number can be negative.

Comment: I think OP is saying: "If 0 is entered, nothing should be printed."

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I do not see this phrase.

Comment: The OP clearly states `while (number > 0)`. If you enter `0`, then the `while` loop will not execute.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis. It is funny. Why do not you accept that it is simply an error?! The task that is announced is to split a number into digits and insert commas between two digits. Zero is a valid number.

Comment: This answer makes too many assumptions about the intent of the program without also providing the correct way to do it without making the assumptions.  Vlad, your answer could easily provide the solution without the assumptions and also include a comment about the case of the user entering 0, and provide this code which handles that.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why should he accept that a person answering the question knows the **intent** of the program better than the person asking the question?  Most likely this is a homework assignment, and any homeworks I ever had like this all said something along the lines of "When the user enters 0, the program should quit".

Comment: @ nhgrif I saw many such code of beginners. And usually it is simply an error. So I am strongly sure that here is also an error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The problem continues to be that you're making an assumption WITHOUT providing what would be the correct answer without the assumption.  If you are strongly sure that it is an error, that's fine, and it's fine to include the correct code to solve that error, but for me to change my downvote into an upvote, the answer will have to include the solution that doesn't make that assumption.

Comment: @ nhgrif Maybe I said too categorically but all examples of the task I saw before all contain the error. The problem is there is a confusing. The condition for positive numbess can be expressed either as number > 0 or as number != 0. So usually if a beginner choice condition number > 0 it is not mean that he was going to exclude 0. He simply choice number > 0 instead of number != 0. All they make the same error. They place this condition in while loop instead of do-while loop.